# Adding/Updating contentful richtext entry name

Tags: contentful

contentful newbie here:)
while adding a rich text entry I can see the name of the entry is defaulted to `untitled` and can't see any way to change it. any idea how can we add/update names for rich text entries in contentful?

Steps:

- when i click on `Add entry` -> `Generic rich text`
- below screen displayed but was not able to update the entry name

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Contentful DevRel here. Please could you provide a screenshot of your issue to give me some more information? I'm not really sure what you're referring to!

Comment: Although it sounds like you need to go into the entry you've linked to update the name :)

Comment: Hi @whitep4nth3r thanks for your reply, i updated the question with screenshot. please could you let me know if you have any idea on this ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to go into your content model for that Rich text field and create a new field called 'Name' or something like that. It doesn't matter what you call it. Then click 'Create and Configure.' Go to the settings tab. Then check the box to make it the entry title.
See screenshot here:
[image: Contenful image]

Then when you go make a new entry of that content type, you just input a name into that 'Name' field, and it will become your Entry Title.